# From JavaScript - swprintf

Tags: javascript, c++, c, printf

I'm trying to do this `swprintf(hexResult, L"%I64X", result);` from javascript, is this possible? Such that `CityHash64('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox')` is encoded as `E7CF176E110C211B`.

Thanks

Comment: There is no `swprintf()` in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript numbers have a `toString` method which takes a radix.  Using `toString(16)` will get you the number in hex.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate its behavior here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/other-licenses/nsis/Contrib/CityHash/CityHash.cpp#78

Comment: @Noitidart This answers your question. You just take the resulting hash value generated in `CityHash64` and use `toString` to convert it to hexadecimal text string -  `hashString = hashValue.toString(16);`.